# Hotkey for resizing the VS Code sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to resize the sidebar with a hotkey? For example, I currently have the `"workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth"` command bound to a key. But it appears that there is not a `"workbench.action.decreaseSidebarWidth"` command.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this which works well for me. Add this to your "keybindings.json". I have Swedish keyboard layout, so you might need to change the "key" part.

```
{
    "command": "runCommands",
    "key": "alt+[ArrowLeft]", // whatever keybinding
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        // commands to run in sequence
        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
        "workbench.action.decreaseViewSize"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "command": "runCommands",
    "key": "alt+[ArrowRight]", // whatever keybinding
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        // commands to run in sequence
        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
        "workbench.action.increaseViewSize"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you!